# galaxy3 update that keeps updating for 3 days plus!

Tags: updates, ota-update

My Galaxy 3 said there was an update to 4.3 available. So I connected a charger and started the upgrade. It warned me that I cannot use phone while upgrading, even for an emergency, bla bla. Of course, I continued with the upgrade, and it went through a couple of processes and then said android is now rebooting!

After it reboot, it came back on saying was upgrading my apps.

That was 3 days ago and is still saying it. I've taken the battery out, put it in, switched it off then on, etc. As I'm typing this, it's still saying the same thing! I can't do a thing with it now!

Any ideas to what is going on? Or is my phone now rendered useless?

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely that your phone is useless. From the symptoms you state, it sounds like you have done one or more of the following,

- Rooted your phone
- Unlocked the bootloader
- Installed a custom recovery
- Installed a custom ROM

If even any one of these is true, the OTA update will fail and redownload itself because it thinks it was a bad package download.

Comment: Thanks for your input,apreciate all the help but unfortunatly iv not rooted the fone,and iv made absolutly no changes at all! i simply agreed to terms&cond and clicked update! im still learning i wouldnt have a clue how to do any of the above. my son pointed out app i was all but out storage?idn any clues as  how i can stop it from continuing to repeat update! as we speak its still going! oh gawd trust me! thanks anyway

Comment: Could you ask your son if he did any of these without your knowledge? I'm afraid its peculiar that something of this sort should happen on a normal device. Also are you sure, its the same update package (4.3) and not a update to 4.3 (so like 4.3.1)?